# How to parse attribute from xml with `find` in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xml-parsing

I am learning javascript and I have small `info.xml` like this:

```
<Check>
    <Meta>
        <Admin>William Taylor</Admin>
        <ID>1234</ID>
    </Meta>
    <Allusers>
        <User>
            <Moved count="9"/>
        </User>
        <Total old="8" new="10"/>
    </Allusers>
</Check>
```

How can I load data with attribute `count` (9), `old` (8) and `new` (10) from .xml above using this method?

```js
var xml="<Check><Meta><Admin>William Taylor</Admin><ID>1234</ID></Meta><Allusers><User><Moved count='9' /></User><Total old='8' new='10'/></Allusers></Check>";
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml)
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$admin = $xml.find("Admin");
$id = $xml.find("ID");
$("#Admin").append($admin.text());
$("#ID").append($id.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ='frame'>
    <div class='div1'>
        <table class='table1'>
            <tr>
                <td>Admin</td>
                <td id="Admin"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td id="ID"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No. moved users</td>
                <td id="count"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No. old users</td>
                <td id="old"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No. new users</td>
                <td id="new"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the selectors below to get what you want, using the same idea:

```
$moved = $xml.find('Moved').attr('count');
```

```
$old = $xml.find('Total').attr('old');
```

```
$new = $xml.find('Total').attr('new');
```